# How to append existing keys by value in python dictionary?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a shopping cart based on sessions on Flask.

Idea is simple:

1. Customer clicks "Add to cart" button with hidden inputs `product_id` and `qty`
2. This POST query adds new record in session["cart"] dictionary

   ```
   [{'qty': '1', 'product_id': '6'}, 
   {'qty': '1', 'product_id': '6'},
   {'qty': '1', 'product_id': '6'}]
   ```
3. I catch this fields and append them in session dict by:

   ```
   session["cart"].append(dict({'product_id': id, 'qty': qty}))
   ```

Every time someone add product in cart it add new record `{'product_id': id, 'qty': qty}` in cart session.

How to check if this `product_id` already in dictionary and if it does, increment just `qty` but don't create new record in dictionary with same `product_id`?

My **Add to cart**:

```
@app.route('/add-to-cart', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_to_cart():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = int(request.form['product_id'])
        qty = int(request.form['qty'])

        cart_session()

        matching = [d for d in session['cart'] if d['product_id'] == id]
        if matching:
            matching[0]['qty'] += qty

        session["cart"].append(dict({'product_id': id, 'qty': qty}))

        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

**Solution**

```
@app.route('/add-to-cart', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_to_cart():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = int(request.form['product_id'])
        qty = int(request.form['qty'])

        cart_session()

        matching = [d for d in session['cart'] if d['product_id'] == id]
        if matching:
            matching[0]['qty'] += qty
        else:
            session["cart"].append(dict({'product_id': id, 'qty': qty}))

        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a dictionary with `product_id` as keys and `qty` as values? Then you could use `defaultdict(int)` as your dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way in python to look for objects in a list is to use list comprehension:

```
matching = [d for d in session['cart'] if d['product_id'] == id]
if matching:
    matching[0]['qty'] += int(qty)
else:
    session['cart'].append(dict({'product_id': id, 'qty': int(qty)}))
```

Comment: this solution works but it creates [{'product_id': '6', 'qty': '11111'}, {'product_id': '6', 'qty': '1'}, {'product_id': '6', 'qty': '1'}, {'product_id': '6', 'qty': '1'}, {'product_id': '6', 'qty': '1'}] for 0 element in array it adds qty from behind but also adds same product

Comment: My code was not meant to be a complete solution to use as is, just a hint on how to go... For the first element, it's because you store the quantity as a string, you should use an int (`matching[0]['qty'] += int(qty)`). And for the other elements, it's probably because you still have your old code that is always executed.

Comment: i convert two values to integers id = int(request.form['product_id']) and qty = int(request.form['qty']) so now all works fine but somewhere is a issue with my algorythm

Comment: thank you for your help and right solution we made it!

Comment: You have to add the dictionary only when it is not there already, see my updated code to show you.

Answer (score 3):

Like [**`rlbond`**`has already suggested`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594269/how-to-append-existing-keys-by-value-in-python-dictionary#comment53042466_32594269), use `defaultdict`, something like this:

```
cart = defaultdict(int)
for product_id, qty in d.iteritems():
    cart[product_id] += qty
```

So in this case if an entry with some key `product_id` does not yet exist in the `cart` dict, it will be initialised to `0` automatically and incremented.

Comment: maybe look in more simple way to solve this question and try to manipulate with session["cart"] and post_id in it